# how to get getServletContext() in spring mvc Controller

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, file-upload

I need to upload images in my project. How to get the upload path in SpringMVC.
The path is;

```
/home/cme/project/eclipse/workspace_12_11/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/fileUploadTester/upload
```

The following error;

```
The method getServletContext() is undefined for the type HomePageController
```

appears when I use this code;

```
String uploadPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("") + File.separator + UPLOAD_DIRECTORY;
```

My code is

```
public ModelAndView UploadPhoto(@ModelAttribute User user, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
 final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "upload";
 final int THRESHOLD_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 3; // 3MB
 final int MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 40; // 40MB
 final int MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 50; // 50MB

 String value[] = new String[10];
 int i = 0;

 // checks if the request actually contains upload file
 if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
  PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
  writer.println("Request does not contain upload data");
  writer.flush();
  return; //here is error This method must return a result of type ModelAndView
 }

 DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
 factory.setSizeThreshold(THRESHOLD_SIZE);
 factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));

 ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
 upload.setFileSizeMax(MAX_FILE_SIZE); //here error The method setFileSizeMax(int) is undefined for the type ServletFileUpload
 upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE);
 String uploadPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("") + File.separator + UPLOAD_DIRECTORY; // here error The method getServletContext() is undefined for the type Homepage Controller
 // creates the directory if it does not exist
 File uploadDir = new File(uploadPath);
 if (!uploadDir.exists()) {
  uploadDir.mkdir();
 }

 try {
  List < FileItem > items = upload.parseRequest(request); // request is HttpServletRequest
  for (FileItem item: items) {
   if (item.isFormField()) { // text fields, etc...
    String fieldName = item.getFieldName();
    System.out.print("fieldname" + fieldName);
    value[i] = item.getString();
    System.out.print("from uploader" + value[i]);
    i++;
   } else {
    //String fileName=new File(item.getName()).getName();   Use this to use default file name
    String name = value[0];
    System.out.println("file uploader name" + name);
    String filePath = uploadPath + File.separator + name;
    System.out.println(filePath);
    File storeFile = new File(filePath);
    try {
     item.write(storeFile);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
   }
  }
  System.out.println("uploaded successfully");
 } catch (Exception ex) {
  System.out.println("error not uploaded");
 }
 return new ModelAndView("ChangePhoto");
}
```

Three error

1. This method must return a result of type ModelAndView
2. The method setFileSizeMax(int) is undefined for the type ServletFileUpload
3. The method getServletContext() is undefined for the type Homepage Controller

Answer (score 94, accepted):

1. Use below code to autowire `ServletContext` object in SpringMVC

   ```
   @Autowired
   ServletContext context;
   ```

   and after that try to execute your code like

   ```
   String uploadPath = context.getRealPath("") + File.separator + UPLOAD_DIRECTORY;
   ```
2. You can get it in your controller like this;

   ```
   private ServletContext context;

   public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
       this.context = servletContext;
   }
   ```

   but for this your controller must implement `ServletContextAware` interface

Answer (score 24):

Try this:

```
@Autowired
ServletContext servletContext;
```

Answer (score 16):

This is just another alternative

```
((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getServletContext()
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameters you passed or set to the ServletContext object, are stored into HttpServletRequest object, you can access them anywhere in application in following way:

```
public void method(HttpServletRequest request){
    String email=request.getServletContext().getInitParameter(“email”);
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation why this code should solve the issue.