# I have few files in a folder, how can I save the path of the files into database by using spring mvc?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

[This is my project folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUwZ6.jpg)

I want to save the file path into database by using spring mvc

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include the code in the post here, because links can quickly/easily get outdated if the URL changes. This leaves your post without any sort of backing to what you're talking about

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ServletContext.getRealPath()`. See first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923907/how-to-get-getservletcontext-in-spring-mvc-controller).